# Keep a Redis connection alive in Haskell

Tags: haskell, redis

I followed the tutorials for creating a rest api with a db and Redis cache on [mmhaskell](https://mmhaskell.com/real-world/redis). Everything works well until I use Redis for caching, then every requests takes about 1 second to complete.

After some research I found that this is probably because the connection is created anew every time I check the cache. This is done with the following method.

```
runRedisAction :: RedisInfo -> Redis a -> IO a
runRedisAction redisInfo action = do
  connection <- connect redisInfo
  runRedis connection action
```

Every time a REST GET request is made I check if the requested entity is already in the cache, which means the connection is created for every request. Checking if a user is already in the cache is done like this:

```
fetchUserRedis :: RedisInfo -> Int64 -> IO (Maybe User)
fetchUserRedis redisInfo uid = runRedisAction redisInfo $ do
  result <- Redis.get . pack . show $ uid
  case result of
    Right (Just userString) -> return $ Just (read . unpack $ userString)
    _ -> return Nothing
```

and this is called with every GET.


How do I prevent the connection being built anew every time in Haskell, in Python for example, I could just move the connection variable to a higher scope.

One way I considered was to pass the connection to the REST API when starting it in the main method, but then I would have to restart everything if the connection should for some reason disconnect.


Hopefully I managed to clearly state the problem, feel free to ask if you need any more information :)



PS: I use Servant for the Rest API, a locally installed Postgresql DB and Hedis as my Redis library

Comment: you should pass the connection as a parameter. Hedis uses resource-pool package to avoid recreating the connections unnecessarily.

Comment: If I pass it as a parameter, how would I handle it correctly if the Redis server goes down for a moment and the connection pool throws an exception? How would I correctly restart the pool? Sorry if the questions are a bit dumb, but this is my first real functional language and I'm still a beginner in Haskell.

Comment: It is not that different from other Python.  The library itself manages the connections. Therefore there is no need to manually restart the connection-pool. You just need handle exceptions thrown in a session like you would do in any other platform.

Comment: Oh, I thought after an exception the connection pool has to be restarted, that solves the problem then, thank you very much